# usort multisort array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

I have array that I need to sort by another array form 2 fields zip code and approve

I am able to sort it by zip code but unable to do it with approved field so for eg

I need to sort by 60007,60001,60003,60002 **(as per sortlike order)**
all zip code from 60007 and approved should come first so

```
$sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
$array1= array(
    array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0)
)
```

**so 60007 and aproved should come first than 60007 with 0(unapproved) and than all 60001 approved than all 60001 unapproved(and so on as per `$sortlike`) here is complete php code**

```
<?php
$array1= array(
    array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 104,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 106,'zip_code' => 60001,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 188,'zip_code' => 60022,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 184,'zip_code' => 60022,'approved' => 1),
);
function sort_results ($a, $b) {
   $sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
   if (!in_array ($a['zip_code'], $sortLike)) { return 1; } // Push unknown values at the end of the array
   return array_search($a['zip_code'], $sortLike) > array_search($b['zip_code'], $sortLike);
}

usort ($array1, 'sort_results');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're asking how you can also sort by `'approved'`, because that is currently missing in your code.

The solution to this question is to define an order in which the keys of your input array `$array1` are checked.

So you need to check `zip_code` at first. If you get a result != 0, you can return immediately. But if the result is == 0 (the zip codes are equal) you need to check the second key (`'approved'` in your case).

```
$array1= array(
    array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 104,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 1),
    array('ID' => 106,'zip_code' => 60001,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 188,'zip_code' => 60022,'approved' => 0),
    array('ID' => 184,'zip_code' => 60022,'approved' => 1),
);
function sort_results ($a, $b) {
    $sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
    if (!in_array ($a['zip_code'], $sortLike)) { return 1; } // Push unknown values at the end of the array
    $zip_res = array_search($a['zip_code'], $sortLike) - array_search($b['zip_code'], $sortLike); // check zip_code order 
    if($zip_res == 0){ // if the zip_codes are equal
        $zip_res = $b['approved'] - $a['approved']; // sort by the 'approved' key
    }
    return $zip_res;
}
```

**//edit**

You can use a lamda function to move `$sortLike` out of the function like this (requires PHP >= 5.3):

```
$sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
$sort_results = function ($a, $b) use ($sortLike){ // create lambda function with "use" keyword
    if (!in_array ($a['zip_code'], $sortLike)) { return 1; } // Push unknown values at the end of the array
    $zip_res = array_search($a['zip_code'], $sortLike) - array_search($b['zip_code'], $sortLike);
    if($zip_res == 0){
        $zip_res = $b['approved'] - $a['approved'];
    }
    return $zip_res;
};

usort ($array1,$sort_results); // pass lambda function in
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Comment: This is what I need and seems very faster as compared to other solutions, Can you help putting $sortLike outside the sort_results as sort_result is an array that comes from database , so $sortLike has to be passed as an argument to call to usort

Comment: Sure, you can use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php) to do that easily. I update the answer to include the corresponding code. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($array_data, array($sort_obj = new cmpArray('array_key'), "cmp__"));
class cmpArray
     {

         var $key;

         function __construct($key)
         {
             $this->key = $key;
         }

         function cmp__($a, $b)
         {
             $key = $this->key;
             if($a[$key] == $b[$key])
                 return 0;

             return (($a[$key] > $b[$key]) ? 1 : -1);
         }

     }
```

Comment: in place of array_key you write your array key on which you want to sort your array

Comment: I am looking to sort on 2 array elements 
1) zip code 2) approved field

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array1= array(
array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),
array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0),
array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0),
array('ID' => 104,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 1),
array('ID' => 106,'zip_code' => 60001,'approved' => 0),
array('ID' => 188,'zip_code' => 60022,'approved' => 0),
array('ID' => 184,'zip_code' => 60022,'approved' => 1),
);

function sort_it ($a) {
$sortedarr = array();
$sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
foreach($sortLike as $el){
    array_push($sortedarr,getElements($a,$el));
}
}



function getElements($arr,$e){
$newarr = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    if($val['approved'] == '1' && $val['zip_code'] == $e){
    $newarr[] = $val;
    }
}
foreach($arr as $val){
    if($val['approved'] == '0' && $val['zip_code'] == $e){
    $newarr[] = $val;
    }
}
return $newarr;
}

$array2 = sort_it($array1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array2);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`usort()` PHP < v7.4: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1QlTL))

```
$priorityZips = array_flip([60007, 60001, 60003, 60002]);
$priorityCount = count($priorityZips);

usort($rows, function($a, $b) use ($priorityZips, $priorityCount) {
    return [
               $priorityZips[$a['zip_code']] ?? $priorityCount,
               $a['zip_code'],
               $b['approved']
           ]
           <=>
           [
               $priorityZips[$b['zip_code']] ?? $priorityCount,
               $b['zip_code'],
               $a['approved']
           ];
});
```

---

`usort()` PHP >= v7.4: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lrMUf))

```
$priorityZips = array_flip([60007, 60001, 60003, 60002]);
$priorityCount = count($priorityZips);

usort($rows, fn($a, $b) =>
    [
        $priorityZips[$a['zip_code']] ?? $priorityCount,
        $a['zip_code'],
        $b['approved']
    ]
    <=>
    [
        $priorityZips[$b['zip_code']] ?? $priorityCount,
        $b['zip_code'],
        $a['approved']
    ]
);
```

---

`array_multisort()` PHP < v7.4: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ps65S))

```
$priorityZips = array_flip([60007, 60001, 60003, 60002]);
$priorityCount = count($priorityZips);

array_multisort(
    array_map(
        function($row) use ($priorityZips, $priorityCount) {
            return $priorityZips[$row['zip_code']] ?? $priorityCount;
        },
        $rows
    ),
    array_column($rows, 'zip_code'),
    array_column($rows, 'approved'),
    SORT_DESC,
    $rows
);
```

---

`array_multisort()` PHP >= v7.4: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ps65S))

```
$priorityZips = array_flip([60007, 60001, 60003, 60002]);
$priorityCount = count($priorityZips);

array_multisort(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => $priorityZips[$row['zip_code']] ?? $priorityCount,
        $rows
    ),
    array_column($rows, 'zip_code'),
    array_column($rows, 'approved'),
    SORT_DESC,
    $rows
);
```

---

In my snippets above, I refer to your input array to be sorted as `$rows`.

This task can be performed several ways, but I've shown a few that I feel are cleanest / most readable.  If performance is critical in your application, I'll encourage you to benchmark using your own real data; otherwise choose the snippet that you are most comfortable maintaining long-term.

In PHP versions below 7.4, passing variables into custom function scopes is done using `use()`. In PHP7.4 and higher, "[arrow function syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php)", strips away a fair chunk of syntax in the custom function and allows the entry of variables without `use()`.

The "[spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30365346/2943403)" / "three-way comparison operator" (`<=>`) makes building multi-criteria sorting MUCH cleaner and concise versus a bunch of condition blocks. The spaceship operator will synchronously process the elements in the arrays and return the correctly evaluated `-1`, `0`, or `1`. It will also treat numeric strings as numbers.

I flipped the lookup array of prioritized zipcodes to enable the "[null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)" (`??`) to swiftly return the priority value or else  default to a number greater than the highest integer value in the lookup.

Regarding the structure of the usort arrays being compared, you may like to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175345/2943403) that goes into a bit more detail.